# "Bundling" solution for HTML/JS only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bundling-and-minification, deferred

I'm sure someone is going to tell me why this is an awful idea, but it may be better than what we have going on already. So all our plugins have been copied/pasted into a Master.js script which is a nightmare to update or sort through. Most of the plugins are minified (which is good) but I'd really like to take the idea of bundling from .net/c#/aspx and implement something of the likes to rid this Master.js file. Copying/pasting new scripts will often freeze the project and nearly everything in it is outdated - so here's my mad science:

In Master.js, create an array of all scripts used:

```
var scripts = [
    'jquery-1.10.2.min.js', // jQuery v1.10.2 | 2005 (https://code.jquery.com/)
    'jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js', // jQuery Migrate v1.2.1 | 2005 (https://code.jquery.com/)
    'jquery-ui.min.js', // jQuery UI v1.10.3 | 2014-09-14 (https://code.jquery.com/)
    'bootstrap.min.js', // Bootstrap v3.1.0 | 2014 (http://getbootstrap.com)
];
```

and create a loop to add scripts to the page:

```
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {

    var link = 'MainJS/' + scripts[i];

    LoadJsCssFilePortal(link, 'js');

};

function LoadJsCssFilePortal(filename, filetype, callback) {

    // if filename is a external JavaScript file
    if (filetype == "js") {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);

    };

    if (typeof fileref != "undefined") {

        // add this script to the document
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    };


};
```

I also have the function

```
function LoadAndRunPortalJS(url, callback) {

        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";

        if (script.readyState) {  //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            script.onload = function () {
                callback();
            };
        }

        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);


};
```

which has a build in callback and is called as such

```
LoadAndRunPortalJS(link, function () {
    // when done load next
});
```

The issue is that the scripts are not finished loading before

1. the next increment in the loop
2. the other scripts on the page that are dependent on Master.js

Typically, one could use the jquery deferred object to enforce the order/completion of scripts so this could possibly be used after the first script (jquery) is loaded i > 0 - but this does not solve the issue of the scripts running outside of master.

Comment: This problem has been comprehensively solved by reasonable build processes (Gulp, Grunt, etc.) and plugins for them (minifiers, bundles). The solutions continue to evolve; amusingly, with HTTP/2 and ES2015 modules, in a few years we may not feel the need for bundling anymore (we'll still need minification). In any case, I don't see a question here, at least not one narrow enough for an SO answer.

Comment: I'm working in Visual Studio and the backend code is handled with C# but I cannot change the extension of the pages. I know if they were aspx, bundling would be possible - but I do not have that option.

Comment: @triplethreat77 — That shouldn't negatively  affect your ability to implement a build time bundle / minify process.

Comment: @Quentin I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the domain of script loaders/bundlers. You might consider using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) for out of the box solutions. If you still want to roll your own, read on.

I'd replace the array of file names you have, with a more resilient structure of the sort

```
var manifest = [
    {key: 'jquery', file: 'jquery-1.10.2.min.js'}
    ...
}
```

This should handle any future versioning issues that may popup (it will). The array structure also preserves your loading order (would not recommend such a method).

On page load, only the manifest described above would be loaded. Any `on load` functions that you would want to call, have to be deferred until scripts are loaded. I would recommend using a method similar to how ad managers (example, google ads) handle it.

```
var onBootloaderInit = [/* array of functions */];
....
onBootloaderInit.push(
    function() {
        /* Code inside can now use jQuery or the likes */
    }
);
```

Once loading has finished, you would now simply iterate through the `onBootloaderInit` array, and execute each function.

To ensure that scripts are loaded in the order you require, and waits for scripts that have been queued, use a script loader (example, [LABjs](http://labjs.com/documentation.php)).

```
$LAB.script('<path to jQuery>').wait(function() {
    /* Code that depends on jQuery */
});
```